# Repeat the previous row in a database based on conditions using python

Tags: python, pandas

I've been stuck on this for a while now.
I want to repeat the previous row and iterate the time to one second before the next row (Please see the output below). In my code, I've attempted the task with pandas. The condition for this repeat command should be when "a" column reads "Power_change" **AND** when the "indicator" column reads above 1 then repeat previous row.

The Input:

| a | P0 | P1 | time | Indicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ISALIVE | 325 | 350 | 10:59:40 | 31 |
| POWER_CHANGE | 200 | 42333 | 10:59:52 | 11 |

This is what I was thinking...

Code:

To sort and filter the data

`s = df.loc[(df['a'] == "POWER_CHANGE") & (df['indicator'] > 1)]`

The problem I have is inserting the previous row

The Output:

| a | P0 | P1 | time | Indicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ISALIVE | 325 | 350 | 10:59:40 | 31 |
| ISALIVE | 325 | 350 | 10:59:40 | 31 |
| POWER_CHANGE | 200 | 42333 | 10:59:52 | 11 |

Comment: please upload a subset of data and clarify your goal

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand why the table looks like that. It looked fine in the preview

Answer (score 0):

fileter the data, use `index - 1` to get the previous row. then append the origin dataframe.

```py
cond = (df['a'] == "POWER_CHANGE") & (df['Indicator'] > 1)

# calculate the time is 1 second before POWER_CHANGE
obj_time = (pd.to_datetime(df.loc[cond, 'time']) - \
            pd.to_timedelta('00:00:01')).dt.strftime('%T')

# get the previous record before 'POWER_CHANGE'
idx = df.loc[cond].index - 1
dfn = df.loc[idx].copy()

# reassign the time, use `.values` to ignore the index
dfn['time'] = obj_time.values

df.append(dfn).sort_index()
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to change the time in the newly inserted row to a second before the time in the "Power_change" row? So in the example above, it'd be 10:59:51

Comment: update the answer with 1s gap with the `Power_change `